# open cursor failing

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am using embedded SQL (`.pgc` files) of PostgreSQL and a cursor to retrieve from a table

```
 EXEC SQL DECLARE mycur CURSOR FOR select col1 from table limit 10;
 if(sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
    {
         os << "error while declaring mycur" << endl;
    }
 EXEC SQL OPEN mycur;
```

`OPEN mycur` is failing. How can I find the reason of failure?

Comment: Typically anything, when failing, should produce an error message or code. In your case it would be the value of `sqlca.sqlcode` _after_ the `OPEN` call.

Comment: error code returning is -400

Answer (score 1):

The [`sqlca` structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ecpg-errors.html#ECPG-SQLCA) also contains an error message field, `sqlerrmc`, which you can use to obtain the error details.

According to the same page linked above SQLCODE -400 means

> Some error caused by the PostgreSQL server. The message contains the error message from the PostgreSQL server.

So, look at the message.

Comment: Thanks every one for replies.

Comment: PREPARE stmt2 .... ;EXEC SQL DECLARE mycur CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR stmt2; Adding the WITH HOLD has solved the issue..not sure it has to be added but same me

Comment: The problem was probably that you were not inside an explicitly started transaction. `WITH HOLD` will materialize the cursor result on the server, which has negative performance implications.